# Kubernetes flask app w/ multiple containers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a kubernetes cluster with 1 pod and 3 containers inside it. One container is a flask app and it redirects the appropriate request to one of the two other containers based on the request.

The problem is my flask app is only able to access one container. Below is my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-service
  labels:
    run: flask-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: flask
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
---  
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask  
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask
        image: gcr.io/translatefx/flask
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
      - name: tagatag-container
        image: gcr.io/XXX/tagatag
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8501
      - name: defined-terms-container
        image: gcr.io/XXX/defined_terms
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8501
```

If my deployment includes both containers (as shown below), only one will work.

```
      - name: tagatag-container
        image: gcr.io/XXX/tagatag
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8501
      - name: defined-terms-container
        image: gcr.io/XXX/defined_terms
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8501
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: replicas: 1 is the number of pods

Comment: sorry, i meant one pod and 3 containers inside it

Comment: You almost always want to do this with three separate Deployments and matching Services.  That lets you scale the three parts separately and lets you update one of the images without restarting the other two containers.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze but wouldn't this force me to use 3 separate pods? And possibly waste more resources?

Comment: Yes, you'd run three separate pods, but it'd be the same number of containers, and I would expect the resource consumption to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run multi-containers in only one Pod.

You should run several containers in a Pod to listen on different ports

```
        image: gcr.io/XXX/tagatag
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8501
      - name: defined-terms-container
        image: gcr.io/XXX/defined_terms
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8502
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but i still had problems, let me try this again..

Comment: In addition to modifying pod manifest and changing port numbers, don't forget to modify your image/app with updated port numbers.

Comment: Weirdly 8502 doesn't work but 8501 does.. am I missing something? (I also updated my image/app port numbers)

Comment: You have to configure defined-items image is working on port 8502

Comment: Get a terminal into non-working container, run curl http://localhost:8502, are you getting expected output?

Comment: I ended up deploying three containers and three separate services for each container to communicate with. Maybe that was the smarter thing to do all along.